# In JavaScript, how can I update each element of an array the same way without using a loop?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops

For example, if I have an array:

```
movies = ["Spider Man", "Avatar", "Titantic", "Avengers"]
```

How do I turn the **movies** array into

```
[{title: "Spider Man"}, {title: "Avatar"}, {title: "Titantic"}, {title:"Avengers"}]
```

without using a loop? Is it possible to do it in **O(1)**?

In the same way, If I have an integer array and need to increment every element by one, can I do it without a loop?

Comment: Why did you hate `Array.map()`, `Array.forEach()` ... ?

Comment: @MisterJojo Because you have to loop through them, which takes time. What if you need to change every element the same way, let's say increment 1 to every element to an integer array? The optimal solution is to do this all at once? right?

Comment: You have a problem to solve in javascript language, but you don't want to bend to its syntax, right ?

Comment: @MisterJojo I have no problem with its syntax. Just wanna know if there is a way to do it in less than O(n)

Comment: there is no syntax of that in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible.

If your input set contains N elements, you cannot create a different structure of N other elements without a loop. Any algorithm that isn't hard-coded to the input array will require an `O(n)` loop.

The only (cheating) `O(1)` approach would be something like

```
const transformMovies = () => [{title: "Spider Man"}, {title: "Avatar"}, {title: "Titantic"}, {title:"Avengers"}];
```

which of course only works for one possible input, and not for the general problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest regex, open to discussion on the complexity of the process

```js
const movies = ["Spider Man", "Avatar", "Titantic", "Avengers"]

let moviesStr = JSON.stringify(movies); // O(1)

moviesStr = moviesStr.replace('["', '[{"title":"') // O(1)
moviesStr = moviesStr.replace('"]', '"}]') // O(1)
const regex = /,"/ig;

moviesStr = moviesStr.replaceAll(regex, '},{"title":"') // O(1) ???

const updateObj =  JSON.parse(moviesStr);

console.log(updateObj)
```